# Filezilla - You do not have permission to list this directory

Tags: macos, filezilla

While I'm trying to upload files from my Mac, I get this message in "Local Site" file list:

**You do not have permission to list this directory**

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 15):

You need to give FileZilla access to files on your disk.

1. On your Mac, go to **System Preferences | Security & Privacy**
2. On the left window, select **Full Disk Access**
3. On the right window, add and select the **FileZilla** application.

On FileZilla:

1. Select **Edit | Directory access permissions**
2. Enter the directories that you want to access.

Note that you can only start searching from the directory you provided.  If you start higher in the directory structure, you cannot navigate down to your directory.

Comment: As per normal Stackoverflow has the answer where the actual application forum does not. If you do the above just add your primary hard drive, so /, and you will get complete access.

Comment: i dont have Edit | Directory access permissions??